# how to parse table inside table using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried this:
`s = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "view"})` But it is giving me the table. But I need the table inside table.

```
<table class="view" >
    <tr>
        <td width="46%" valign="top">
        <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="adasdasd">
                <div class="abc">dasdsadasdasdas</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span><span class="aaaaaaa " title="aaaaaaaaaaa"><span>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></span> </span>
                <b>My Face</b><br />
                    Hello This is me,
                </div>
            <div class="abc"">
                    Dec 6, 2010 by Alis
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
    </table>

The things I want to scrap is:

    Hello This is me,

    My Face

    Dec 6, 2010 by Alis
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "view"})[0].find("table")
```

If there's just the one table, you could use `.find` for the first one too, and drop the `[0]`.

Comment: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'- Attribute Error I am getting.

Comment: If you're using findAll, you need the [0] as well. findAll gives you a ResultSet (like a list), so you need to specify that you want to use the first one found. If it just finds that one table on the page, you can use find instead of findAll to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Heres some better formatted html:

```
<table class="view" >
    <tr>
        <td width="46%" valign="top">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="adasdasd">
                            <div class="abc">dasdsadasdasdas</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <span class="aaaaaaa " title="aaaaaaaaaaa">
                                    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <b>My Face</b>
                            <br />
                            Hello This is me,
                        </div>
                        <div class="abc">
                            Dec 6, 2010 by Alis
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: I actually added a  tag because it was missing one.

```
innerTable = soup.find("table", {"class": "view"}).tr.td.table ##Gets the table in the first cell of the first row

innerDiv = innerTable.find("div", {"style": "adasdasd"}).nextSibling #this gets the div in which all of you content resides
```

So that will get you to that  that holds all of your content. From there it's just a little bit of parsing to get the content you actually need.